# What is the proper way to handle a large number of interface implementations?

Tags: c++, interface

For one of my current projects I have an interface defined for which I have a large number of implementations. You could think of it as a plugin interface with many plugins.

These "plugins" each handle a different message type in a network protocol.
So when I get a new message, I loop through a list of my plugins, see who can handle it, and call into them via the interface.

The issue I am struggling with is how to allocate, initialize, and "load" all the implementations into my array/vector/whatever.

Currently I am declaring all of the "plugins" in main(), then calling an "plugin_manager.add_plugin(&plugin);" for each one. This seems less than ideal.

So, the actual questions:
1. Is there a standardized approach to this sort of thing?
2. Is there any way to define an array (global?) pre-loaded with the plugins?
3. Am I going about this the wrong way entirely? Are there other (better?) architecture options for this sort of problem?

Thanks.

EDIT:

This compiles (please excuse the ugly code)... but it kind of seems like a hack.
On the other hand, it solves the issue of allocation, and cleans up main()... Is this a valid solution?

```
class intf
{
public:
    virtual void t() = 0;
};

class test : public intf
{
public:
    test(){}
    static test* inst(){ if(!_inst) _inst = new test; return _inst; }
    static test* _inst;
    void t(){}
};
test* test::_inst = NULL;

intf* ints[] =
{
    test::inst(),
    NULL
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store some form of smart pointer in a container. Dynamically allocate the plugins and register them in the container so that they can be used later.

One possible approach for your solution would be, if you have some form of message id that the plugin can decode, to use a map from that id to the plugin that handles that. This approach allows you to have *fast* lookup of the plugin given the input message.

Comment: Currently I am storing pointers to the plugins in a QVector (QT). The bigger issue is where is the proper place to allocate/declare all these plugins - my main() is looking rather ugly. You are correct that I am mapping message id's to plugins. A map may perform better than the vector (though I am not sure... there are not THAT many plugins)... however there are a few cases where multiple plugins want to receive events for the same message id's (multimap?).

Comment: @TreeMonkie: From the description in your question it looks like you allocate the plugins in `main` and pass pointers to the stack allocated objects. My suggestion is not *dynamically allocate* (i.e. `new`) the plugins and store a smart pointer in the container (so that you don't need to track them). You can also use a map of vectors with all the plugins that should receive a single event, but whether this is better or worse than the plain vector depends on the number of plugins and usage patterns.

Comment: So is `main()` the proper place to actually allocate all of the plugins? Are there any other options you would recommend? Maybe I'm making a big deal out of nothing... but it feels _wrong_ to have a `main()` that is a couple hundred lines long. However, there isn't any solution that is obvious to me that is better.

Comment: @TreeMonkie: It does not need to be main, but just any other function. One of the advantages of dynamically allocating the plugins is that they can outlive the context in which they are created. Depending on the particular use case you could have a plugin loader that looks up for plugins and dynamically loads libraries, calling a standardized function in the library to create the plugins, or you could have a function that process the configuration and based on that loads plugins, or they could be hard coded into `main` or any other function... it all depends on your particular problem to solve

Answer (score 2):

One way of writing less code would be to use templates for the instantiation function. Then you only need to write one and put it in the interface, instead of having one function per implementation class.

```
class intf
{
public:
    virtual void t() = 0;

    template<class T>
    static T* inst()
    {
        static T instance;
        return &instance;
    }
};

class test : public intf { ... };

intf* ints[] =
{
    intf::inst<test>(),
    NULL
};
```

The above code also works around two bugs you have in your code: One is a memory leak, in your old `inst()` function you allocate but you never free; The other is that the constructor sets the *static* member to `NULL`.

Other tips is to read more about the "singleton" pattern, which is what you have. It can be useful in some situations, but is generally advised against.